# Android ViewPager with ListViews Performance

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have just finished a project where I have a Fragment Activity with 3 Fragments(each one has 2 listviews each). It works akin to Google Play Store (horizontal swipe views).

I had some lag when swipping the views which I improved by caching some variables inside the custom adapters I created. Nevertheless, since I haven't already implemented all the columns in these listviews I fear I will run into some performance hiccups later on - used the ViewHolder pattern from the beginning.

With this in mind I googled a way to load the listviews in each page just once given that I will be updating the dataset only when starting each fragment, but to no luck.

Does anyone knows a way to this? Also I leave part of my code here if you have some advice in order to increase performance (I will probably switch the headers listviews with textviews):

**ScoreBoardAdapter.java**

```
public class ScoreBoardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TeamItem>{
    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<TeamItem> _items;
    private String TAG = "ScoreBoard Adapter";
    private Typeface _typeface;
    private int colorPos;
    private int[] colorsRow = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#F0F0F0"), Color.parseColor("#D2E4FC") }; 
    private static class ViewHolder{
        TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
    }   

    /* Esta ArrayList terá que ser substituida/preenchida por um objecto JSON vindo do webservice */
    public ScoreBoardAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<TeamItem> items){
        super(activity, 0, items);
        Log.i(TAG,"Constructor call");
        this._activity = activity;
        this._items = items;
        this._typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(_activity.getAssets(), "GOODTIME.ttf");
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = _activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scoreboard_body, null);
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scoreboard_body_tv1);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scoreboard_body_tv2);
            holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scoreboard_body_tv3);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        //Fetch input data
        TeamItem lv_item =  _items.get(position);
        holder.tv1.setText(lv_item.getTeam());
        holder.tv2.setText(lv_item.getGames());
        holder.tv3.setText(lv_item.getPoints());

        //Change font
        holder.tv1.setTypeface(_typeface);
        holder.tv2.setTypeface(_typeface);
        holder.tv3.setTypeface(_typeface);

        //Change row color
        colorPos = position % colorsRow.length;  
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorsRow[colorPos]);

        return convertView;
    }

//Mudar os nomes das variaveis quando souber o que cada uma representa (equipa, pontos, etc...)
}
```

**ScoreBoardFragment.java**

```
public class ScoreBoardFragment extends Fragment {
    View rootView;
    ListView lvHeader, lvTable;

    // Dados da tabela
    private String jsonInput = "[{\"Equipa\":\"Benfica\",\"Jogos\":7,\"Pontos\":2},{\"Equipa\":\"Sporting\",\"Jogos\":1,\"Pontos\":1},{\"Equipa\":\"Porto\",\"Jogos\":8,\"Pontos\":1},{\"Equipa\":\"Moreirense\",\"Jogos\":4,\"Pontos\":4},{\"Equipa\":\"Braga\",\"Jogos\":7,\"Pontos\":8},{\"Equipa\":\"Guimarães\",\"Jogos\":2,\"Pontos\":2},{\"Equipa\":\"Rio Ave\",\"Jogos\":9,\"Pontos\":0},{\"Equipa\":\"Paços de Ferreira\",\"Jogos\":6,\"Pontos\":5},{\"Equipa\":\"Boavista\",\"Jogos\":0,\"Pontos\":9},{\"Equipa\":\"Estoril\",\"Jogos\":5,\"Pontos\":3}]";
    private ArrayList<TeamItem> teamItemArray;

    // Cabeçalho
    private String[] inputHeaders;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lv_headers;
    HashMap<String, String> headerMap;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        inputHeaders = new String[] {
            getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.equipa),
            getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.jogos),
            getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.pontos) };

        /**** Preencher os headers da tabela ***/
        fillHeaders();

        /**** Preencher o body da tabela ***/
        fillBody();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scoreboard, container,
            false);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void fillBody() {
        teamItemArray = new TeamItem().retrieveArrayFromJson(jsonInput); // input
                                                                        // data
        lvTable = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.f_scoreboard_lvbody);

        ScoreBoardAdapter listAdapter = new ScoreBoardAdapter(getActivity(),
            teamItemArray);
        lvTable.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    private void fillHeaders() {
        lvHeader = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.f_scoreboard_lvheader);
        lv_headers = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headerMap.put("1", inputHeaders[0]);
        headerMap.put("2", inputHeaders[1]);
        headerMap.put("3", inputHeaders[2]);
        lv_headers.add(headerMap);

        try {
            ListAdapter listAdapterHeader = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                lv_headers, R.layout.scoreboard_header, new String[] { "1",
                        "2", "3" }, new int[] { R.id.scoreboard_header_tv1,
                        R.id.scoreboard_header_tv2,
                        R.id.scoreboard_header_tv3 });

            lvHeader.setAdapter(listAdapterHeader);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**SectionsPagerAdapter.java**

```
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Activity _activity;
    private List<String> fragments; // serve para guardar os fragmentos
                                // (screens) da aplicação

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Activity activity) {
        super(fm);
        this._activity = activity;
        fragments = new ArrayList<String>();

        fragments.add(ScoreBoardFragment.class.getName());
        fragments.add(FixturesFragment.class.getName());    
        fragments.add(TopScorersFragment.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return Fragment.instantiate(_activity, fragments.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Return number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return _activity
                .getString(com.eurom.ciftest.R.string.classificacao)
                .toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return _activity.getString(com.eurom.ciftest.R.string.jornada)
                .toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return _activity.getString(
                com.eurom.ciftest.R.string.melhores_marcadores)
                .toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using your FragmentPagerAdapter with a ViewPager. In this case try setting the ***offscreenPageLimit*** to a value higher than 1. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) for details

Comment: Thank you very much! Tried it and no more calls to the adapter when swipping through the views.